# BigQuery allow_large_results does not work as expected

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

Run API at Google cloud to call big query.

My program is like this:

bigquery_client = bigquery.Client();

def bq(q):

```
query_results = bigquery_client.run_sync_query(query);
query_results.use_legacy_sql = True;
query_results.allow_large_results = True;
query_results.destinationTable = {"projectId": my id,"tableId": my table, "datasetId": my dataset};
query_results.run();

return query_results
```

The result I get is still part of the full results, limited to 10 M data. How can I circumvent this limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`allowLargeResults` (if set to true) allows the query to produce arbitrarily large result tables at a slight cost in performance. Requires destinationTable to be set.
You still limited in getting result to your client so to get whole result you need page through the results

If expected result less than 128 MB you do not need to save/store it in table and can just page through result - see [`pageToken`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/query#pageToken)

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! Is there any method to fetch results > 10 M and store into server rather than store as a table?